# NDSolve breaking down

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I'm trying to model a situation involving charged sphere in a dynamic electric potential, and find out how the rotational motion of the sphere affects the translational dynamics in two dimensions. Here `q0` refers to charge at the centre of the sphere, whereas `q1` is charge deposited at its surface, which will lead to a torque. `ωd` is the driving frequency of the electric field. My model seems to work well in certain limits, but breaks down in the region I'm actually interested in. My equations are

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveProblems`"];
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveUtilities`"];
eqns1 = {
    x''[t] == - (1/m) E0 Cos[ωd t] (q0 x[t] + q1 Abs[Sin[ϕ[t]]] (x[t] + R Sin[ϕ[t]])) 
         - γt x'[t],
    y''[t] == -(1/m) E0 Cos[ωd t] (q0 y[t] + q1 Abs[Cos[ϕ[t]]] (y[t] + R Cos[ϕ[t]])) 
         - γt y'[t] - 9.8 m,
    ϕ''[t] == 1/MI E0 Cos[ωd t] q1 R (-Cos[ϕ[t]] (x[t] + R Sin[ϕ[t]]) +  
         Sin[ϕ[t]] (y[t] + R Cos[ϕ[t]])) - γr ϕ'[t],
    x'[0] == xv0,
    ϕ'[0] == ϕv0,
    x[0] == x0,
    ϕ[0] == ϕ0,
    y'[0] == yv0,
    y[0] == x0};
```

I then have a list of parameters (which I'll at the end of the post), including the initial values. I solve the equations using

```
sol[p_, time_] := 
  NDSolve[eqns1 //. p, {x[t], ϕ[t], ϕ'[t], x'[t], y[t], y'[t]}, {t, 0, time},
  MaxSteps -> ∞, "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Indeterminate &, "WarningMessage" -> False}];
```

Where I have experimented with a number of `Methods`, including `"StiffnessSwitching"`, `"BDH"` , `"ExplicitRungeKutta"` and `"ImplicitRungeKutta"`. This does work with certain parameters, basically when `q0` is large and `q1` is low, but breaks down if I try to switch those values, making `q1>q0`. I run this with `time=1`. Here are the parameters which do work:

```
p = {
   m -> 2000 4/3 π R^2,
   R -> 10^-7,
   E0 -> 10^14,
   MI -> 5/2 m R^2,
   q0 -> q0b eV ,
   q0b -> 100,
   q1 -> q1b eV,
   q1b -> 5,
   eV -> 1.602 10^-19,
   γt -> 1,
   γr -> 1,
   ωd -> 15000,
   xv0 -> 10^-2,
   ϕv0 -> 1,
   x0 -> 10^-9,
   y0 -> 10^-9,
   yv0 -> 10^-2,
   ϕ0 -> π/10};
```

However it breaks down when I send `q0b-> 5, q1b-> 100`. The error code I get is:

```
At t == 0.099279970214417`, step size is effectively zero; 
singularity or stiff system suspected
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: What is the value of `time`?  Also, `Cos[ω d t]` should be `Cos[ωd t]`

Comment: Ok, updated to address these points. Typically running it with `time=1`.

Comment: Look at your equations numerically (`eqns1 //. p // N`) and work on normalizing things to get rid of the numerically large/small values. ( introduce `tprime=t wd` , `xprime=X/R` etc. ). It may not help, the system may simply be too unstable to integrate.

Comment: @DanGoldwater  It turns out that your system of equations is chaotic, and this probably explains the problems we both had solving them.  I am sending you this comment, because I prepared an answer, deleted it, edited it, and finally undeleted it.  I have learned the hard way that you will not receive any notice of the new version of the answer.  Best wishes.

Comment: I think you'd better explain the model a little more, for example, the meaning of all the parameters and the original equation etc.… Well, actually what I want to say is, are you sure the equation set is correct? I'm not familiar with electromagnetism, but I guess the `-9.8` is gravity acceleration? If so, then why it's multiplied by `m`?

Answer (score 2):

In the course of trying to solve this problem, I have run a number of physical and numerical parameters. The most striking behavior that I observed is extreme sensitivity of the results to those parameters.  This suggests that the system is chaotic, especially for large `q1b`.  To illustrate this extreme sensitivity, compute `ϕ` for fixed values of `x` and `y`:

```
sc = NDSolveValue[{ϕ''[t] == 1/MI E0 Cos[ωd t] q1 R (-Cos[ϕ[t]] (x + R Sin[ϕ[t]]) +  
    Sin[ϕ[t]] (y + R Cos[ϕ[t]])) - γr ϕ'[t], ϕ'[0] == 1, ϕ[0] == π/10} //. 
    p /. {x -> 4*10^-5, y -> 2*10^-5}, {ϕ, ϕ'}, {t, 0, 1/100}];
ParametricPlot[{sc[[1]][t], sc[[2]][t]/ωd /. p}, {t, 0, 1/100},
    AxesLabel -> {ϕ, ϕ'}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

with `q0b -> 5, q1b -> 100`.

[image]

In contrast, increasing `y` to `2.01*10^-5` yields

[image]

Thus, although

```
sol[p_, time_] := NDSolve[eqns1 //. p, {x[t], y[t], φ[t],}, {t, 0, time}, MaxSteps -> ∞, 
    MaxStepFraction -> 10^-3/(ωd time) /. p, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"];
```

gives a stable answer, at least out to `time = 1/10`,

[image]

changing anything produces a very different answer.  Sometimes that different answer is unstable, sometimes not.